# Is your wall the same as your timeline on Facebook?

Tags: facebook-timeline

Would like to post to my "wall". Is that the same as the timeline? How does the timeline differ from the newsfeed?

Answer (score 2):

Your wall is your timeline, it was renamed awhile back when they changed some stuff. The area where you see other people's activity is the newsfeed.